# Excel SumProduct with if Statement in a cell.

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, vba

I have a basic problem in Excel. I have a row with names and one with numbers. I try to find what is the sum of these numbers for a special name.

ex.

```
 A        B
Apple     12
Apple     12
Kiwi      9 
Apple     4
Banana    51
Kiwi      12
Banana    4 
Kiwi
```

So far I just use a basic sumproduct which works well. Like

```
=Sumproduct((A1:A8=A1)*(B1:B8)
This formula gives me back my total number of Apples
(12+12+4).
```

The problem is, if a cell contain some formula, then I have #VALUE! result. 
Let say the last cell called Kiwi contain a code like

```
=if(A64="", "", 12) 
Then it makes Kiwi empty if A64 is empty. Great.
```

But sumproduct don't work anymore.

I can't sort the name... any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `=SUMIF()` formula to get sum of these numbers for a special name.

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$B$64,A1,$B$1:$B$64)
```

or

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$B$64,"kiwi",$B$1:$B$64)
```

You can change these ranges based on your list. (You can even define dynamic name in `Name Manager` and then you can use that **Name** *as your range*.)

Answer (score 1):

It's not the fact that your cell is calculated (contains a formula), it's because the result of the formula is a text.

Maybe you could use à 0 instead of the 0-length text and apply conditional formatting to your cells (font colour white if 0 value)

```
    =if(A64="", 0, 12)
```